# Using jQuery keynav plugin with live()

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events, uikeyboard

I have a website with two columns, in the first is a form and the second an ajax generated series of divs. I need keyboard friendly navigation and so far jQuery plugin keynav is doing a good job.

But if I want the key navigation to extend over the divs that are added to DOM I would need to use live() and I'm having trouble figuring out. I assumed it would be something like this:

```
$(document).live('keyup', function(){
    $('input, button, .restu').keynav('keynav','keynav');
});
```

Where "restu" is the class of the generated divs. But that's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use delegate:

```
$(document).delegate('div', 'keyup', function(){
    $('input, button, .restu').keynav('keynav','keynav');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try window instead of document

```
$(window).live('keyup', function(){
    $('input, button, .restu').keynav('keynav','keynav');
});
```